# WL.Client.connect onSuccess callback does not get called

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

Given the following code, the onSuccess is not being called back on a successful connect. I've listed the code and log output for the sequence of events. Is the code set up wrong? connectOnStartup is set to false in the initOptions. This code is also in the Shell project with the logcat coming from the Inner project using the Shell:

```
function onConnectSuccess(){
    console.log ("CSXMobile:onConnectSuccess");
    WL.Logger.debug("CSXMobile:onConnectSuccess");
}

function onConnectFailure(){
    WL.Logger.debug("CSXMobile:onConnectFailure");
}

function disconnectDetected(){
    WL.Logger.debug("CSXMobile:disconnectDetected");
}

function connectDetected(){
    WL.Logger.debug("CSXMobile:connectDetected");
}

function wlCommonInit(){

    WL.Logger.debug("CSXMobile:wlCommonInit");
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, connectDetected, false); 
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, disconnectDetected , false);

     WL.Client.connect({
         onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
         onFailure: onConnectFailure
     });
}
```

As seen in the logs here wlCommonInit is being called and logged, but the log statements in the onConnectSuccess is never written...

```
11-21 13:49:01.460: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): wlclient init started
11-21 13:49:01.460: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): Read cookies: null
11-21 13:49:01.460: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
11-21 13:49:01.507: D/dalvikvm(6341): GC_CONCURRENT freed 311K, 4% free 11407K/11783K, paused 2ms+16ms, total 34ms
11-21 13:49:01.507: D/CordovaNetworkManager(6341): Connection Type: wifi
11-21 13:49:01.507: D/DroidGap(6341): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
11-21 13:49:01.507: D/DroidGap(6341): onMessage(spinner,stop)
11-21 13:49:01.507: D/CordovaLog(6341): CSXMobile:csxmobileDeviceReady
11-21 13:49:01.507: I/Web Console(6341): CSXMobile:csxmobileDeviceReady at file:///data/data/com.csx.CSXMobileShellTest/files/www/default/js/CSXMobile.js:172
11-21 13:49:01.538: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): CSXMobile:deviceOnline
11-21 13:49:01.546: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): before: app init onSuccess
11-21 13:49:01.546: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): CSXMobile:wlCommonInit
11-21 13:49:01.561: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): Request [https://myworklightserver/query]
11-21 13:49:01.585: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): after: app init onSuccess
11-21 13:49:01.585: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): added onPause event handler 
11-21 13:49:01.585: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): wlclient init success
11-21 13:49:01.858: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): isCustomResponse
11-21 13:49:01.858: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): isCustomResponse true
11-21 13:49:01.858: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6341): handleChallenge
11-21 14:14:57.796: D/DroidGap(6656): onMessage(spinner,stop)
11-21 14:15:08.975: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): Request [login]
11-21 14:15:09.132: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): Status =401
11-21 14:15:09.132: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): isCustomResponse
11-21 14:15:09.139: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): isCustomResponse false
11-21 14:15:09.147: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): Request [https://myworklightserver/query]
11-21 14:15:09.163: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): hideLogin
11-21 14:15:09.413: D/Cordova(6656): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.csx.CSXMobileShellTest/files/www/default/CSXMobileShellTest.html#testMainPage)
11-21 14:15:09.413: D/Cordova(6656): Trying to fire onNativeReady
11-21 14:15:09.413: D/DroidGap(6656): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
11-21 14:15:09.413: D/DroidGap(6656): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.csx.CSXMobileShellTest/files/www/default/CSXMobileShellTest.html#testMainPage)
11-21 14:15:09.475: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): Request [https://myworklightserver/query]
11-21 14:15:09.522: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): Request [https://myworklightserver/query]
11-21 14:15:09.616: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): isCustomResponse
11-21 14:15:09.616: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): isCustomResponse false
11-21 14:15:09.616: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): CSXMobile:connectDetected
11-21 14:15:09.647: D/CSXMobileShellTest(6656): response [https://myworklightserver/query] success: /*-secure-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to ping a contact at IBM and get feedback. We are implementing the challengeHandler in conjunction with WL.Client.createChallengeHandler. One of the key items I omitted was doing a challengeHandler.submitSuccess(); after a successful login. Once I added that line in the successful login routine, everything worked fine.